# Expected number of steps to get N red balls choosing K at a time

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

I have a problem that can be reduced to a classic box with red and black balls.

> We have a box containing $N$ red balls and $M$ black balls. Taking $K$ balls at a time (**without** replacement), what is the expected number of tries I need to get all $N$ red balls.

After looking similar questions I see we need to calculate the expected value of the given probability distribution, but can't figure out which one is it.

Let's take a look at an example of what we are looking at:

Assume N=3, M=8 and K=2.

- In the best case, after 2 tries I'd already found 3 red balls (i.e., 2 at the 1st and 1 at the 2nd, or viceversa).
- In the worst case, it will take 6 tries to take the red balls (i.e., I'll first find all black balls). *There are actually many variations of this worst case where I find some red ball before, but the last at the end*.

But, how to define this "average" expected case?

Comment: This is not clear. In your example, why isn't the worst case infinite?  After all, since we are replacing after each draw, you can just keep choosing black balls forever.

Comment: For $k=1, M=0$ this is the [Coupon Collector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  Probably a good idea to study this example first.  Note;  I'm assuming that the red balls are numbered, no?  Else what does it mean to "get all of them"?

Comment: @lulu that was an error, not it is fixed. I meant without replacement (i.e., elements are taken out of the box). I was unfamiliar with the english term, it sounds so unnatural to say "without replacement" to mean that elements are actually replaced.

Comment: Still not clear.  So you mean "without replacement", yes?  Meaning that you take the $K$ balls out and never put them back in the box?  In that case I agree with your example.

Comment: Exactly, just want to know how many times I'll need to take K balls on average to find the N red ones

Comment: There is an obvious recursion....that is, if you are starting with the system $(M,N)$ then the first draw takes you to $(M-a,N-b)$ where $a+b=K$.  That at least gives you a way to compute the answer rapidly for modest $M,N$.  (of course, to get the recursion you need to compute the probability that your draw gets you $a$ red ones and $b$ black).

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_j$, for $N+M \ge j \ge N$, be the number of sequences of $M+N$ red and black balls where $N$ red balls occur within the first $j$ balls and the $j$th ball is red.

$S_j = {j-1 \choose N-1}N!M!$, since there are $j-1 \choose N-1$ unique sequences of $N-1$ positions for red balls in $j-1$ slots, $N!$ permutations of red balls, and $M!$ permutations of black balls.

Then, we define $p_j$ to be the probability that a sequence of $S_j$ occurs.

$$p_j = \frac{S_j}{(N+M)!} = \frac{j-1 \choose N-1}{N+M \choose N}$$
Assuming for now that $K=1$, we find that the expected number of tries, $E_1$, is

$$E_1 = \sum_{t=N}^{N+M} t p_t = \frac{1}{N+M \choose N}\sum_{t=N}^{N+M}t{t-1\choose N-1} = \frac{N}{N+M \choose N}\sum_{t=N}^{N+M}{t\choose N}=N\sum_{k=0}^{M}\frac{P_{N+t,t}}{P_{N+M,M}}$$

For $K > 1$, $E_K$ is just regrouping the probabilities $p_t$ and then multiplying by the number of tries.

$$E_K = \sum_{t=\lceil N/K \rceil}^{\lceil N+M/K \rceil} t \left(\sum_{v=0}^{K-1}p_{Kt+v}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple example $N=3$, $M=3$, and $K=2$. The possible draws to choose all 3 red balls in this case are (If I missed any possibility, correct me please)

RR
RB = 2 steps with probability $p_1$ (R = red, B = black)

RB
RB
RB = 3 steps with probability $p_2$

RB
RR = 2 steps with probability $p_3$

RB
BB
RR = 3 steps with probability $p_4$

RR
BB
RB = 3 steps with probability $p_5$

BB
RB
RR = 3 steps with probability $p_6$

BB
RR
RB = 3 steps with probability $p_7$

You need to calculate the probability of each event above. The expected/average number of steps is calculated as in

$$\sum_ip_ix_i$$

where $p_i$ is the probability and $x_i$ is the number of steps for event $i$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest case is when $K=1$ in which case the expected number appears to be  $\dfrac{N(N+M+1)}{N+1}$, a result related to $\sum\limits_{j=0}^M \frac{M \choose j}{N+M \choose j} = \frac{N+M+1}{N+1}$

There may or may not be quite such a simple expression for general $K$, and having $K$ not needing to divide $N+M$ may complicate the issue, but it should be slightly larger than $\dfrac{N(N+M+1)}{K(N+1)}$

For example, with $N=3$, $M=8$ and $K=1$, I think the expected number of tries is $9$.  This suggests that with $K=2$ it should be slightly more than $4.5$; detailed calculation seems to give $2 \times \frac{4}{165}+3 \times \frac{16}{165}+4 \times \frac{36}{165}+5 \times \frac{64}{165}+6 \times \frac{45}{165}=\frac{158}{33} \approx 4.79$.  The squares in that cacluation hint at some possibilities worth investigating further

Comment: How do you prove that first identity?

Comment: @player100 : see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012811/showing-sum-limits-j-0m-fracm-choose-jnm-choose-j-fracnm1n