# Showing $\sum\limits_{j=0}^M \frac{M \choose j}{N+M \choose j} = \frac{N+M+1}{N+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In an [answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3011064/6460), I stated $$\sum\limits_{j=0}^M \frac{M \choose j}{N+M \choose j} = \frac{N+M+1}{N+1}.$$

It is clearly true when $N=0$ since you add up $M+1$ copies of $1$, and when $M=0$ since you add up one copy of $1$.  And, for example, with $M=4$ and $N=9$ you get $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{4}{13}+\frac{6}{78}+\frac{4}{286}+\frac{1}{715} = \frac{14}{10}$ as expected.

But how might you approach a general proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{M \choose j}{N+M \choose j}=\frac{\binom{N+M-j}{N}}{\binom{N+M}{N}}.$$
Hence, we can rewrite the sum as
$$\sum_{j=0}^M \frac{M \choose j}{N+M \choose j}=\frac{1}{\binom{N+M}{N}}\sum_{j=0}^M \binom{N+M-j}{N}=\frac{1}{\binom{N+M}{N}}\sum_{i=N}^{N+M} \binom{i}{N}.$$
Finally use the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: That seems to work well. In my example of $M=4,N=9$ this represents $\frac{715}{715}+\frac{220}{715}+\frac{55}{715}+\frac{10}{715}+\frac{1}{715} = \frac{1001}{715}=\frac{14 \choose 10}{13 \choose 9}=\frac{14}{10}$

Comment: @Henry Well done!!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{j = 0}^{M}{{M \choose j} \over {N + M \choose j}} =
> {N + M + 1 \over N + 1}:\ {\LARGE ?}}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 0}^{M}{{M \choose j} \over {N + M \choose j}} & =
\sum_{j = 0}^{M}{M!/\bracks{j!\pars{M - j}!} \over
\pars{N + M}!/\bracks{j!\pars{N + M - j}!}}
\\[5mm] & =
{M!\, N! \over \pars{N + M}!}\sum_{j = 0}^{M}
{N + M - j \choose M - j} 
\\[5mm] & =
{M!\, N! \over \pars{N + M}!}\pars{-1}^{M}
\sum_{j = 0}^{M}\pars{-1}^{j}
\bracks{z^{M - j}}\pars{1 + z}^{-N - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
{M!\, N! \over \pars{N + M}!}\pars{-1}^{M}
\bracks{z^{M}}\pars{1 + z}^{-N - 1}\,
{\pars{-z}^{M + 1} - 1 \over \pars{-z} - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
{M!\, N! \over \pars{N + M}!}\pars{-1}^{M}
\bracks{z^{M}}\pars{1 + z}^{-N - 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{M!\, N! \over \pars{N + M}!}\pars{-1}^{M}
\braces{{-\bracks{-N - 2} + M - 1 \choose M}\pars{-1}^{M}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{N + M + 1 \over N + 1}
\end{align}