# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{m \choose k}}{{n \choose k}}= \frac{n+1}{n-m+1}, m \le n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{m \choose k}}{{n \choose k}}= \frac{n+1}{n-m+1}, m \le n$$
I have carried out enough numerics to find that this identity is true. So, here, I  raise the question of its  reference and a proof.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, it is corrected it now.

Comment: "I have carried out enough numerics to find that this identity is true." Either that's a full proof on its own, or you haven't really carried out enough numerics to find that it is true. You can try enough examples to _suspect_, or even _believe_ that it's true. But if it's not a full proof, then you can't say that it's true, and if you can say that it is true, then what you have is a full proof.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing $\sum\limits_{j=0}^M \frac{M \choose j}{N+M \choose j} = \frac{N+M+1}{N+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012811/showing-sum-limits-j-0m-fracm-choose-jnm-choose-j-fracnm1n) with $m=M$ and $n=M+N$; the sum should be from $0$ to $m$ rather than to $n$

Comment: @Henry for $k>m$ the $\binom{m}{k}$ is zero

Comment: @Henry while posting this question your question did not pop up in the list of similar questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember to have seen this result earlier. Let us prove it using two existing identities $${n\choose m} {m \choose k}={n \choose k} {n-k \choose m-k} ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ \sum_{p=0}^{n} {p \choose j}= {n+1 \choose j+1}.$$
Denoting the required sum as $S$, we can write that
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{m \choose k}}{{n \choose k}}=\frac{1}{{n \choose m}}. \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n-k \choose m-k} =\frac{1}{{n \choose m}}. \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n-k \choose n-m}=
\frac{1}{{n \choose m}}. \sum_{p=0}^{n} {p \choose m-n}.$$
$$\Rightarrow S= \frac{{n+1 \choose n-m+1}}{{n \choose m}}=\frac{n+1}{n-m+1},~~~ \mbox{if}~~ m \le n.$$